# How to create multilevel options menu in flutter?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

i want to create this ui ( multi level options menu)

> in which at at traling part of question we can add image view as well as in options we can add image view.

can any one help me how can i achive this ui. is there any package available for multi level dropdwon menu?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's widget named `ExpansionTile`:

wrap container with InkWell and onTap select unselect option, you can change border color as per state of selection

[[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc74h.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc74h.png)

```
ExpansionTile(
              textColor: Colors.indigo,
              title: const Text("Question"),
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  primary: false,
                  itemCount: 3,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        //select code here
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          border: Border.all(
                            width: 2,
                            color: Colors.blue,// take bool for changing active border color like this: isActive ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey
                          ),
                        ),
                        child:  Center(child: Text("$index")),
                      ).paddingAll(10),
                    );
                  },
                ),

              ],
            ),
```

Comment: yes this is wat i want but now question is how can i select that one?

Comment: i have to show options and after selecting any of one goto next.

Comment: edited my answer hope you will get clearity thanks!